# Visual Studio HTML RegEx Replace

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a large project that has been developed over the span of about 20 years and it is massive.  There's a modification that needs to be done to 300 or so pages, with about 2800 actual replacements.  This brings me to desire to use Visual Studio's RegEx to do the actual replacement.

It is in a pseudo-HTML file of another file type that is passed to a parser that 'executes' code based on certain commands, and outputs HTML text.  The syntax I am working with contains regular HTML code with calls like such:

```
<div id="outer-box" <__@BGCOLOR>>            //Basic call
<div id="outer-box" <__@BGCOLOR TOGGLE"1">>  //Call with toggle (only) parameter
```

Now what I need to do is change it to:

```
<div id="outer-box" style="<__@BGCOLOR>">
<div id="outer-box" style="<__@BGCOLOR TOGGLE="1">">
```

But here's the problem.  Some tags already have the style attribute declared like so:

```
<div id="inner-box" style="border:1px" <__@BGCOLOR>>  //One possibility
<div id="inner-box" <__@BGCOLOR> style="border:1px">  //Another one
```

Meaning I would need to change it to:

```
<div id="inner-box" style="<__@BGCOLOR>border:1px">
```

I've fought with it for several hours now and cannot seem to get it right.  I should also add that sometimes more than one HTML element will be on a line, and sometimes more than one parser call (with a different command than BGCOLOR) will be in a given element.

What I have so far to find ALL instances of it that I have not already fixed is such:

```
~(style=")\<__\@BGCOLOR{.@}\>
```

**EDIT :** For clarification, this is using [Visual Studio's RegEx syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) and I'm looking specifically for calls to the BGCOLOR command.  I have the RegEx above that is able to find all cases of <__@BGCOLOR[ TOGGLE="1"]> that is not preceded by 'style="' to filter out already fixed items.

Comment: I feel your pain, so I'm going to *attempt* to find a regex that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to start by making some simplifying assumptions about the text.  This is always necessary when trying to match HTML with regexes, but in this case it's mostly to make the regexes easier to read.  The regexes can be corrected to reflect more complicated criteria without changing their basic structure.

- Element and attribute names are always alphabetic (i.e., they match VS's `:w`, or `[A-Za-z]+`).
- Attribute names are always preceded by spaces and/or tabs (`:b+`).
- Attribute values are always quoted (`:q`).
- There are no spaces around the `=` between the attribute name and its value.

Also, notice the way I use the negative lookahead in `~(style):w`.  It says "one or more letters (`:w`), but not if they make up the word `style`".  You're using it as if it were a negative *lookbehind*: "`<__@BGCOLOR{.@}>`, unless it's preceded by `style=`".  A lot of people make that mistake.

I propose a four-step process:

First, match any element with a special token in it and rearrange it so the token is listed after all attributes:

- search: `{\<:w(:b+:w=:q)*}{:b+\<__\@BGCOLOR[^<>]*\>}{(:b+:w=:q)+}`
- replace: `\1\3\2`

Second, if there's a `style` attribute, make sure it's the last attribute listed (but before the special token):

- search: `{\<:w(:b+~(style):w=:q)*}{:b+style=:q}{(:b+~(style):w=:q)+}{:b+\<__\@BGCOLOR[^<>]*\>}`
- replace: `\1\3\2\4`

Third, wrap the special token in a `style` attribute:

- search: `{\<__\@BGCOLOR[^<>]*\>}\>`
- replace: `style="\1">`

Finally, if there are two `style` attributes, merge them:

- search: `style="{[^"]+}":b+style="{\<[^<>]+\>}"`
- replace: `style="\1; \2"`

Starting from this text:

```
<div <__@BGCOLOR> id="inner-box" style="border:1px">
<div foo="bar" id="inner-box" <__@BGCOLOR TOGGLE="1"> style="border:1px">
<div id="inner-box" bar="foo" <__@BGCOLOR>>
<div  id="inner-box" <__@BGCOLOR> style="border:1px">
<div id="inner-box" style="border:1px" <__@BGCOLOR TOGGLE="1">>
<div id="inner-box" <__@BGCOLOR> foo="bar">
```

...I end up with this:

```
<div id="inner-box" style="border:1px; <__@BGCOLOR>">
<div foo="bar" id="inner-box" style="border:1px; <__@BGCOLOR TOGGLE="1">">
<div id="inner-box" bar="foo" style="<__@BGCOLOR>">
<div  id="inner-box" style="border:1px; <__@BGCOLOR>">
<div id="inner-box" style="border:1px; <__@BGCOLOR TOGGLE="1">">
<div id="inner-box" foo="bar" style="<__@BGCOLOR>">
```

I gotta tell ya, Visual Studio is a major handicap here.  It's a great IDE, but its regex flavor is just bizarre.  If you're going to do much of this kind of thing, I strongly recommend you switch to a tool like [EditPad Pro](http://www.editpadpro.com/) or [PowerGrep](http://www.powergrep.com/) that uses a full-featured regex flavor with **standard** syntax.

**EDIT:** I finally did the (relatively) sensible thing and composed the regexes in a Perl-like flavor, mainly to find out if the problem is even solvable with regexes.  It is, and it only took two steps:

search:

```
(
  <\w+\b
  (?:
    \s*
    (?:
      \w+="[^"]+"
    |
      <(?!__@BGCOLOR)[^<>]*>
    )
  )*
  \s*
)
(<__@BGCOLOR[^<>]*>)
(
  (?:
    \s*
    (?:
      \w+="[^"]+"
    |
      <[^<>]+>
    )
  )*
)
```

replace:

```
$1style="$2"$3
```

search:

```
(
  <\w+\b
  (?:
    \s*
    (?:
      (?!style)\w+="[^"]+"
    |
      <[^<>]+>
    )
  )*
  \s*
)
style="([^"]+)"
(
  (?:
    \s*
    (?:
      (?!style)\w+="[^"]+"
    |
      <[^<>]+>
    )
  )*
)
\s*style="([^"]+)"
```

replace:

```
$1style="$2; $4"$3
```

The next step would be to translate that to Visual Studio syntax (if that's even possible), but I'm too tired to start on that right now. ;)  And, as I said before, if you're going to be doing this kind of thing a lot, you should look into writing a dedicated parser, or switching to a tool or language that uses standard syntax (for very loose definitions of "standard").  Whatever you do, quit using Visual Studio's native so-called regexes and you'll be doing everyone a favor. :D

Comment: I have to hand it to you, I didn't expect to have a way to actually find and fix every case.  I'm going to give you another challenge though.  What if the HTML tag has other commands in it?  For example, this parser allows the use of if/else blocks like so:
`<div id="inner-box" <__#IF condition="foo==bar">foo="bar"<__/IF> <__@BGCOLOR>>`
This can break the searches because of the addition of more < and > symbols.  Any ideas?

Comment: It occurred to me later that the case I just gave would still work.  But these ones do not:  
`<div id="inner-box" <__@BGCOLOR> <__#IF condition="foo==bar">foo="bar"<__/IF> style="border:1px">
<div id="inner-box" style="border:1px" <__@BGCOLOR> <__#IF condition="foo==bar">foo="bar"<__/IF>>
<div id="inner-box" <__@BGCOLOR> <__#IF condition="foo==bar">foo="bar" style="border:1px"<__/IF>>`  
This is not a big deal, because the occurrence of this is so low, I can replace these manually without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with (Anyone is free to edit this):

RegEx: `^.*<.*(<.*>(?!")).*>.*$`

That should capture the `<__@BGCOLOR>` area, which you can then replace with whatever suits your needs.